# EXIT_FRAME bubbles up?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, flex4

According to the Flash docs:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#

> The Event.EXIT_FRAME constant defines
>   the value of the type property of an
>   exitFrame event object.
>
> Note: This event has neither a
>   "capture phase" nor a "bubble phase",
>   which means that event listeners must
>   be added directly to any potential
>   targets, whether the target is on the
>   display list or not.

However when calling **gotoAndStop** on a child DisplayObject the EXIT_FRAME event is raised on it's container and there appears to be no way to stop it.

For example:

```
        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
  {
   removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
   // entry point
   c = new Circle2();
   addChild(c);

   this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
   this.addEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME, exitFrame);
  }

  private function enterFrame(e:Event):void
  {
   trace("enter frame");
   c.setPercent(5); // this calls gotoAndStop()
  }

  private function exitFrame(e:Event):void
  {
   trace("exit frame");
  }
```

Output is:

> enter frame
>
> exit frame
>
> exit frame

In Circle2 constructor I've tried this

```
this.addEventListener( Event.EXIT_FRAME, function(e:Event):void
{
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I´m having the same behavior in AS3 - Flash CC Pro. I´m trying to detect the case in the event handler so I can stop the execution before running the real code...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [capture phase](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29) and then call stopPropagation into it.

```
this.addEventListener( Event.EXIT_FRAME, function(e:Event):void
{
    e.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```

Note the **true** at the end of the addEventListener.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it unfortunately made no difference.

Comment: @ChrisPorter did you ever find an explanation for this? I'm experimenting exactly the same situation; several EXIT_FRAME without its corresponding ENTER_FRAME. Thanks!